# Accessing the Current URL in a Text Widget for a Facebook Share Button?

Tags: urls, facebook

I'm creating a *"Share this Page"*- widget that needs to **grab the current URL** and append it to a Facebook URL like this:

> `http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=http://myurl.com/a-specific-page`

I'm using a regular text widget. How can I access the current URL and put it into the sharing link?

Comment: Oh man, this is awesome. Thank you all so much for helping out. I'll tinker with it and get back with results.

Comment: Alright. I used your Share button Mike, just copied the code right into the widget. You can see it here

http://17juni.se

Thanks all of you for a good learning experience.

-Rikard

Comment: Hi *@Rikard* - Glad it helped. Can you mark the best answers with the checkmark and vote up any that are good answers?

Answer (score 3):

*@user653* is correct, you can't do it in a text widget with PHP but you can do it in a text widget using [**JQuery**](http://jquery.com/)/Javascript. Here's how.

#### Starting with the Facebook Share Button HTML

I assume you plan to use use the [**Facebook Share Button**](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/share) and thus will have HTML code in your widget that will look like this?

```
<a name="fb_share"></a>
<script src="http://static.ak.fbcdn.net/connect.php/js/FB.Share"
        type="text/javascript">
</script>
```

#### Use jQuery and `Javascript's windows.location` object.property

If yes then you can **just add all the following code** into your widget:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $("fb_share").attr("share_url") = encodeURIComponent(window.location);
});
</script>
<a name="fb_share"></a><script src="http://static.ak.fbcdn.net/connect.php/js/FB.Share" type="text/javascript">
</script>
```

#### Be sure to Enqueue jQuery in your Theme's `functions.php` File

However, in order for the above code to work you will probably need to enqueue the included jQuery script bundled with WordPress add the following line of code into your theme's `functions.php` (unless some other plugin is already doing so):

```
wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
```

#### Facebook Like Button as a WordPress Shortcode

Ironically just I implemented a **[Facebook Like Button](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like)** as a [Shortcode](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2009/02/02/mastering-wordpress-shortcodes/) a few days ago for a client so I thought I'd also *share* with you (pun intended. ;) You can see how we got the current URL from the `$_SERVER` variable. I scarfed this exact code from the `redirect_canonical()` function in `/wp-includes/canonical.php'`. You can also just include this in your theme's `functions.php` file:

```
add_shortcode('facebook-like','my_facebook_like_button');
function my_facebook_like_button($echo=true) {
  // Generate the HTML required to place a Facebook "Like" button inside a shortcode
  // See Docs: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like
  $requested_url  = is_ssl() ? 'https://' : 'http://';
  $requested_url .= $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
  $requested_url .= $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];  
  $html =<<<HTML
<iframe src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href={$requested_url}&amp;layout=button_count&amp;show_faces=false&amp;width=60&amp;action=like&amp;font=verdana&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;height=21&amp;ref=blog"
        scrolling="no" frameborder="0"  allowTransparency="true" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:90px; height:25px"></iframe>
HTML;
  if ($echo)
    echo $html;
  else
    return $html;
}
```

#### What it Looks Like

Here's a screenshot showing usage. Note that since text widgets [don't process the content filters](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/do_shortcode#Examples) so the shortcode doesn't work in a text widget. I looked quickly and didn't find a plugin that adds text widgets that can process shortcodes but it wouldn't be hard to write one, or hard to write a widget that just adds a Facebook Share or Like buttons either. FWIW.

[image: WordPress Site Screenshot showing Facebook Like and Buttons as Shortcodes and in Text Widgets]

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

Just use the $_SERVER variables:

```
$url = add_query_arg( 'u', $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"], 'http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php' );
```

Comment: NOTE: add_query_arg() does not urlencode: urlencode($_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]) on your own. Please update your answer accordingly.

Comment: *@Joe Hoyle*: Also to @hakre's comment that code doesn't work in Text Widget.

Comment: @MikeSchinkel ahh didn't realise that! Not sure how I got 2 vote ups in that case.

Comment: @hakre Why does it need `urlencode` ing? It's just using the $_SERVER variables just as WordPress does in `add_query_arg()` ( http://github.com/dxw/wordpress/blob/175863359b46ff1b666548104b3502f2fd84d601/wp-includes/functions.php#L1376 ) and that's not `urlencode` ed

Comment: *@Joe Hoyle* - Because people up vote answers that look good without first testing that they work! (hell, I've done it. :)

Comment: *@Joe Hoyle* You need URL encoding because URL parameters could be misinterpreted. Riddle me this, what's the value of the `url` parameter here? http://facebook.com?url=http://example.com?foo=1&bar=2&baz=3

Comment: @MikeSchinkel Ahh of course, I was getting confused with thinking it was encoding the base url, not the param that would be added. Anyway, can I delete my answer as this answer is completely wrong because it uses PHP

Comment: *@Joe Hoyle* - We can vote to delete but I haven't done that yet so not sure what it will take. Want me to vote to delete and you do the same?

Answer (score 1):

You can't make the contents of a text widget dynamic like that.
Get "Executable PHP widget" (http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/php-code-widget/), for example.
Now you can add your text etc including php code to insert the variable URL.

[edit]
Ref http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like.
Put this into your *php code supporting* widget:

```
  <?php global $post; ?>
<iframe src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=<?php echo urlencode(get_permalink($post->ID)); ?>&amp;layout=standard&amp;show_faces=false&amp;width=450&amp;action=like&amp;colorscheme=light" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" allowTransparency="true" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:450px; height:60px;"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's some complete code for you:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<a href="http://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button" data-url="" data-count="vertical" data-via="arkliapp">Tweet</a>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js"></script>
<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1"></script><fb:like id="fb_like" href="" layout="box_count" show_faces="true" width="55" font=""></fb:like>

<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
$("#fb_like").attr("href") = encodeURIComponent(window.location);
$(".twitter-share-button").attr("data-url") = encodeURLComponent(window.location);
});
</script>
```

Comment: That’s not the WordPress way. You never want to load an additional jQuery from a second source. And scripts should be [loaded per API](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script).